# Scipy odeint evaluates at negative time values

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to solve a system of ODEs with `scipy.integrate.odeint` from the boundary condition at the final time and working my way up to the initial time (as described here: [Backward integration in time using scipy odeint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227115/backward-integration-in-time-using-scipy-odeint)).

However, `odeint` iterates to negative time values - outside of the actual range of solutions I'm looking for - and this causes an error because my ODEs depend on the square root of time and my function return a complex value instead of a real number.

Here's an example that reproduces the issue:

```
    import numpy as np 
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    tmax = 4e4
    tmin = 1
    t = np.linspace(tmax,tmin,1e3)
    param0 = [1] #value of x at tmax

    def func(param,t):
        x = param[0]
        dxdt = 1e-10/np.sqrt(t)
        print(t) #show what values of t are tried by odeint
        return dxdt

    res = odeint(func,param0,t)
```

Very rapidly `print(t)` shows negative values and `res` is filled with `nan`.

Is there a way to prevent `odeint` from going to negative values? Why is it trying values outside of my input array `t`?

For my actual code I found some ways to avoid the `nan` results, such as adding `if t<0: t=0` in the function (which wouldn't work here) or by imposing a very small maximal time steps (`hmax<tmin`) but this makes the computation much longer.

Note that [Scipy odeint Non-negative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366858/scipy-odeint-non-negative-solution) is related but my problem is slightly different: I'm not concerned by a negative solution `x`, but by a negative argument `t`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) instead of the old odeint. Note that solve_ivp expects f(t, y) instead of f(y, t) as right hand side of your ode:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
tmax = int(4e4)
tmin = 1
t = np.linspace(tmax, tmin, int(1e3))
param0 = [1] #value of x at tmax

def func(t, param):
    dxdt = 1e-10/np.sqrt(t)
    return dxdt

res = solve_ivp(func, y0=param0, t_span=[tmax, tmin], t_eval=t)
```

where `t_eval=t` ensures that the solution will be stored at the time points `t`. Otherwise the solver chooses the time points.

Comment: Although ```solve_ivp``` doesn't try values outside of ```[tmin, tmax]```, it makes the calculation much slower for my code. I tried different integration methods and none were as fast as ```odeint```. I'll eventually need to solve my ODE system many times for even larger ```tmax``` so I'm afraid it'll take even more time.